# Replce repeating set of character from end of string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove all `<br>` from the end of this string. Currently I am doing this (in javascript) -

```
const value = "this is an event. <br><br><br><br>"
let description = String(value);
while (description.endsWith('<br>')) {
    description = description.replace(/<br>$/, '');
}
```

But I want to do it without using while loop, by only using some regex with replace.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the end of the string in RegEx, you can use the special `$` symbol to denote that.

To identify repeated characters or blocks of text containing certain characters, you can use `+` symbol.

In your case, the final regex is: `(<br>)*$`

This will remove 0 or more occurrence of `<br>` from the end of the line.

Example:

```
     const value = "this is an event. <br><br><br><br>"
     let description = String(value);
     description.replace(/(<br>)*$/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```js
var value = "this is an event. <br><br><br><br>";
var output = value.replace(/(<.*?>)\1*$/, "");
console.log(output);
```

Here is the regex logic being used:

```
(<.*?>)  match AND capture any HTML tag
\1*      then match that same tag zero or more additional times
$        all tags occurring at the end of the string
```